# Linkear por medio de clase o metodo archivo css en php

Tags: php, mvc

He estado desarrollando un proyecto con php, pero acutalmente me encuentro en un problema que es mis archivos php de views tienen linkeado muchos archivos css y js, pero como estoy llamandolos desde un router se pierden esas rutas relativas, se que una solucion seria colocar una ruta absoluta, pero no es lo que desearia para poder ver mejor la estructura de mi proyecto.

**Hay alguna manera de crear un metodo o una clase que pueda hacer que se incluyan esos link de css y js a las views de php?**

> Estoy organizando todo a mvc

tengo bastantes archivos css, js, img y fuentes las cuales quiero linkear, hay alguna librearia o algo parecido para poder establecer algun orden o como podria hacer eso?
Actualmente estoy corriendolo en un server local de nginx

```
.
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   └── models
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── public
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── awards-img
│   │   │   ├── a-1.png
│   │   │   ├── a-2.png
│   │   │   ├── a-3.png
│   │   │   ├── a-4.png
│   │   │   └── a-5.png
│   │   ├── bg-img
│   │   │   ├── about-1.jpg
│   │   │   ├── about-2.jpg
│   │   │   ├── hero-1.jpg
│   │   │   ├── hero-2.jpg
│   │   │   ├── hero-3.jpg
│   │   │   ├── hero-4.jpg
│   │   │   └── hero-5.jpg
│   │   ├── core-img
│   │   │   ├── about-dots.png
│   │   │   ├── point.png
│   │   │   ├── preload-1.png
│   │   │   ├── preload-2.png
│   │   │   ├── preload-3.png
│   │   │   └── special-dots.png
│   │   ├── icons
│   │   │   ├── cancel.svg
│   │   │   ├── email.svg
│   │   │   ├── left-arrow.svg
│   │   │   ├── phone.svg
│   │   │   ├── point.svg
│   │   │   ├── quotation-mark.svg
│   │   │   ├── right-arrow.svg
│   │   │   └── search.svg
│   │   ├── menu-img
│   │   │   ├── dish-1.png
│   │   │   ├── dish-2.png
│   │   │   └── dish-3.png
│   │   └── testimonial-img
│   │       ├── 1.jpg
│   │       ├── 2.jpg
│   │       └── 3.jpg
│   └── index.php
├── regular-page.html
├── resources
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── bootstrap
│   │   │   │   └── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   │   ├── others
│   │   │   │   ├── animate.css
│   │   │   │   ├── font-awesome.min.css
│   │   │   │   ├── magnific-popup.css
│   │   │   │   ├── owl.carousel.min.css
│   │   │   │   └── pe-icon-7-stroke.css
│   │   │   └── responsive
│   │   │       └── responsive.css
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   │   ├── FontAwesome.otf
│   │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
│   │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
│   │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
│   │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.woff
│   │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.woff2
│   │   │   ├── Pe-icon-7-stroke.eot
│   │   │   ├── Pe-icon-7-stroke.svg
│   │   │   ├── Pe-icon-7-stroke.ttf
│   │   │   └── Pe-icon-7-stroke.woff
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   ├── active.js
│   │   │   ├── bootstrap
│   │   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │   │   │   └── popper.min.js
│   │   │   ├── google-map
│   │   │   │   └── map-active.js
│   │   │   ├── jquery
│   │   │   │   └── jquery-2.2.4.min.js
│   │   │   └── others
│   │   │       └── plugins.js
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── views
│       ├── contact.php
│       ├── index.php
│       ├── layouts
│       └── menu.php
└── vendor
```

Comment: Deberías dar mas detalles sobre cual es el caso. Como es la jerarquía de directorios, como las carga en el navegador, que servidor usas: local, maquina virtual, remoto... esto ayuda a evaluar mejor y dar una respuesta más precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede realizar lo siguiente, no sé sí es exactamente lo que buscas, te muestro un ejemplo que utilice:
**js.php**

```
<!-- ESTE ARCHIVO CONTIENE LOS JS GLOBALES.
AL LLAMAR A ESTE ARCHIVO DESDE EL CONTROLADOR SE CARGAN LOS JS. -->
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js/w3codecolor.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js/images.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js/dates.js');?>"></script>
</head>
```

**archivo.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('js.php');
?>
```

No sé sí es la práctica mas recomendada, pero se puede realizar de esa manera. Lo que se pierde es selectividad, es decir todos tus archivos que realicen el require_once cargaran todos los js o css lo usen o no.

Comment: pues si habia visto algo parecido en otra pregunta, pero queria ver que otras soluciones se pueden implementar

Comment: En general la mayoría de los frameworks tienen una carpeta donde debes alojar los archivos JS y CSS, y una referencia absoluta al root como: base_url APP->PATH o cosas así, entonces la idea es manejarte con las constantes del framework.

Comment: bueno, por ahora seguira usando esta forma, hasta que encuentre alguna manera de organizar las cosas